# Filtering Excel "files" that have unique values less than a specific number provided in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 1000 excel files with the same format. Some of those files have multiple unique values in a specific column, whereas some has only 8 to 10. At this moment, i open every single excel file, then manually look for number of unique values in a specific column(Say Column E) and then choose such excel files that have required number of unique values in column E. As you can guess applying this same process to 1000 excel files gives me headaches sometimes. If the unique values in the Column E of a file are less than 10, that file is needed. I want to filter those excel files that contain 8 to 10 values in that specific column.

Comment: That's pretty easy in VBA. Loop through all files in a folder, open each one, count the number of unique values in your range (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17857333/) and save the files that fit your criteria elsewhere.

Comment: If this is Excel 2010, you can install the Power Query add-in and have Power Query read all the files from the folder. Power Query has automation that will look at the first file as a "model" and then read all data from all other files in that folder in the same way. Power Query can easily extract the unique values from all of these files and deliver that as a table in your workbook.